# IDX10503: Signature validation failed after updating to Owin.Security v 4.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, ws-federation, owin-security

As per subject, I updated the `Owin.Security.WsFederation` and dependent packages to version 4.0 and I get the error.

I did not make any code changes other than changing

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
```

to

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation;
```

where is the `WsFederationConfiguration` class seems to be now.

Here is my *StartupAuth*:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(
                new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
                });

            // Create WsFed configuration from web.config wsfed: values
            var wsconfig = new WsFederationConfiguration()
            {
                Issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsfed:Issuer"],
                TokenEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsfed:TokenEndPoint"],                
            };

            /* 
             * Add x509 certificates to configuration
             * 
             */
            // certificate.1 must always exist
            byte[] x509Certificate;
            x509Certificate = Convert.FromBase64String(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsfed:certificate.1"]);
            wsconfig.SigningKeys.Add(new X509SecurityKey(new X509Certificate2(x509Certificate)));
            // certificate 2 may exist
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsfed:certificate.2"] != null)
            {
                x509Certificate = Convert.FromBase64String(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsfed:certificate.2"]);
                wsconfig.SigningKeys.Add(new X509SecurityKey(new X509Certificate2(x509Certificate)));
            }
            // certificate 3 may exist
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsfed:certificate.3"] != null)
            {
                x509Certificate = Convert.FromBase64String(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsfed:certificate.3"]);
                wsconfig.SigningKeys.Add(new X509SecurityKey(new X509Certificate2(x509Certificate)));
            }

            // Apply configuration to wsfed Auth Options
            var wsoptions = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                Configuration = wsconfig,
                Wreply = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsfed:Wreply"],
                Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsfed:Wtrealm"],
            };
            wsoptions.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn";

            // Add WdFederation middleware to Owin pipeline
            app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(wsoptions);
        }
```

Is there something else 4.0 needs to validate the signature? I assume it's talking about the signature of the token from the issuer. I didn't see how to enable ShowPII to see what key it's looking at.

I am using MVC5 with the full framework. Not core.

**Update**:

I tried to modify the code to use the metadata provided by the identity provider in a properties file to create the `WsFederationConfiguration` and I still get the same error. I'm not sure what the Signature is, or where I get it from if it's not in the idp metadata.

**Update2**:

Here are the changes I made to use the wsfed metadata provided by the sts in a properties file. (I have removed the actual base64 encoded metadata, but needless to say it is the same XML you get when you regest the metadata from an STS that publishes it as and endpoint. As I said above, I get the same error:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        WsFederationConfiguration wsconfig;

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
            new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
            });

        var metaDataDocument = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                Convert.FromBase64String("...c2NyaXB0b3I+"));

        using (var metaDataReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(metaDataDocument), SafeSettings))
        {
            wsconfig = (new WsFederationMetadataSerializer()).ReadMetadata(metaDataReader);
        }

        // Apply configuration to wsfed Auth Options
        var wsoptions = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            Configuration = wsconfig,
            Wreply = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsfed:Wreply"],
            Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsfed:Wtrealm"],
        };
        wsoptions.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn";

        // Add WdFederation middleware to Owin pipeline
        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(wsoptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked with some folks on the team at MS. The issue here was that our STS is using SHA1 to sign the token and the new version of weFederation doesn't support SHA1 as it is not-secure and is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to use WIF with owin is through **the usage of the federation meta data** (which lives at *FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml*). **Then you don't need to setup anything at all** which is explained in [Configure claims based web applications using OWIN WsFederation middleware](http://blog.baslijten.com/configure-claims-based-web-applications-using-owin-wsfederation-middleware/) . The precondition is of course that your STS publishes a meaningful `FederationMetaData` document. The nice advantage is that your public keys needed for validation are automatically picked up by your application (and renewing them is done seamlessly).

This is IMHO that is much easier than the approach you are taking.

You can follow [Manual configuration of OWIN WS-Federation Identity provider](http://www.vodovnik.com/2015/04/15/manual-configuration-of-owin-ws-federation-identity-provider/) as it describes a more easy way than yours.

Comment: My STS does not publish the metadata as an endpoint. They do provide it in a properties file. So, I changed the code, as I said in my update to create the WsConfiguration from the metadata in the properties file. I get the same exact error.