# IdentityServer3 - Error Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10503: Signature validation failed

Tags: c#, identityserver4, identityserver3, ws-federation

I am trying to add **WsFederationAuthenticationOption** in my IdentityServer3 implementation as External Authentication Provider . I am using **Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFedrataion** NuGet Package for that. And adding it as external Idenity Provider as  following

```
    public static void ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
    {
         var adfs = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "adfs",
            Caption = "TEST ADFS",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,

            MetadataAddress = 
            "https://adfs.myurl.com/federationmetadata/200706/federationmetadata.xml",
            Wtrealm = "urn:myApp"

        };
        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(adfs);

    }
```

**inside  Authentication Options Setup**

```
     var authenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions()
     {
            RememberLastUsername = true,
            CookieOptions = cookieOptions,
            EnableLocalLogin = true,
            EnableLoginHint = true,
            EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
            EnableSignOutPrompt = true,
            InvalidSignInRedirectUrl =
                                                "https://www.myapp.io/",
            PostSignOutAutoRedirectDelay = 0,
            SignInMessageThreshold = 100,                
            IdentityProviders = ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders,
        };
```

its redirecting me to right ADFS server and showing screen to fill in my ADFS login details . And also on successfull login it returns back to Core url of IdentityServer in my case its like  **https://myIdentityserver.com/Core** etc

But i am getting following errrors in log.

**Caught exception from Owin Middleware
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'.
Exceptions caught:
 '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'.
token: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'.**

I tried to find out way to set ShowPII flag but didn't get any help from Identityserver documentation and also i tried changing requiredSSl option to false. but it didn't help.

Please share your thoughts.What i am missing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. thanks to following post by Pilotbob

[IDX10503: Signature validation failed after updating to Owin.Security v 4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49301972/idx10503-signature-validation-failed-after-updating-to-owin-security-v-4-0-0)

https://forums.asp.net/t/2138093.aspx?IDX10503+Signature+validation+failed+after+updating+to+Owin+Security+v+4+0+0

Issue was Latest version of Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation doesn't support SHA-1 and Relying Party Trust setup on ADFS side should have SHA-256 atleast.

thanks.